# How to run separate fish function when using Windows Terminal and Vscode Terminal

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code, fish

I am trying to run 2 separate fish scripts one which triggers only on the Windows Terminal and the other runs exclusively on Vscode-Insiders Terminal.
Is there any variable set by Vscode which can be fetched inside the fish script to separate out the functions?
I am very new to shell scripting and would appreciate any help to resolve this.

Comment: The `env` command shows all env vars. Is `$TERM` different? Compare `echo $TERM` between the two environments.

Comment: What does _separate out the functions_ mean?